# I can't set meta_key in my custom post type query

Tags: custom-post-types, post-meta, meta-query, custom-post-type-archives

I've created a custom post, `events`, and saved the meta data `event_year` to each event.  I'm trying to get a year's event archive.  When I go the the following URL, the `meta_key` and `meta_value` are not set for some reason, and thus the event archive is unfiltered.

```
/?post_type=events&meta_key=event_year&meta_value=2011
```

Debugging the values:

```
echo $wp_query->query_vars['post_type']; // 'events'
echo $wp_query->query_vars['meta_key']; // -blank-
echo $wp_query->query_vars['meta_value']; // -blank-
```

**Why can't I set the meta_key and meta_value?**

The meta_values are saved to the events.  I've successfully displayed them:

```
get_post_meta($post->ID, 'event_year', true); // '2011'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because 'meta_key' and 'meta_value' are not public query vars. In other words, you can't use them in URLs directly, nor should you.

Instead, register a specific query var, like so:

```
function register_my_qv() {
  global $wp;
  $wp->add_query_var( 'my_qv' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_my_qv' );
```

Then, you can go to a URL like this: `?my_qv=foobar`

All you need to do now is map your query var to the actual query you want to do:

```
function map_my_qv( $wp_query ) {
  if ( $meta_value = $wp_query->get( 'my_qv' ) ) {
    $wp_query->set( 'meta_key', 'some_meta_key' );
    $wp_query->set( 'meta_value', $meta_value );
  }
}
add_action( 'parse_query', 'map_my_qv' );
```

Comment: Okay.  I was using the public URL as a test for a rewrite rule.  Sorry for witholding my ultimate goal.  I want to add this:  `add_rewrite_rule('^events/([0-9]+)$', 'index.php?post_type=events&meta_key=event_year&meta_value=$1');`  Is this still not allowed?

Comment: I'm not sure. You'll just have to try it for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I can't add a comment to the scribu's excellent answer due to low reputation, but still the second part of the code (`map_my_qv` function) while working on WP 4.2 was giving me 404s, missing posts in admin and PHP notices about `$meta_value` variable not set. Therefore, here's the edited code:

```
function map_my_qv( $wp_query ) {
    if ( is_admin() || ! $wp_query->is_main_query() ) 
        return; 

    if ( $wp_query->get( 'my_qv1' ) ) {
        $wp_query->set( 'meta_key', 'my_meta_key1' );
        $wp_query->set( 'meta_value', $wp_query->get( 'my_qv1' ) );
    }
    if ( $wp_query->get( 'my_qv2' ) ) {
        $wp_query->set( 'meta_key', 'my_meta_key2' );
        $wp_query->set( 'meta_value', $wp_query->get( 'my_qv2' ) );
    }
}
add_action( 'parse_query', 'map_my_qv' );
```