# Filter by custom field (meta_key) using JSON API

Tags: custom-field, meta-value, plugin-json-api

Hi I'm using the great [JSON API](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/json-api/other_notes/) for Wordpress and would like to filter my custom post types by a specific custom field (using the meta_key and meta_value params).

The query in my URL looks like this so far:

> http://example.org?json=get_recent_posts&post_type=mytype&custom_fields=myfield&include=title,custom_fields&meta_key=myfield&meta_value=myvalue

However, it still returns all the posts (from that post type), no matter whether or not they contain the custom field mapping.

What's wrong?
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You should show some code - actually the one with which you're trying to receive the post.

Comment: Well, if you know the WP JSON API - that's all there is. After installing the plugin, you can request JSON data by typing a URL such as written in my question.

Comment: I don't know it and I guess there are not too many people who know it, so I'll just guess. See answer.

Answer (score 1):

As this is too much for a comment, I'll post here and delete later:

```
http://example.org // domain
?json=get_recent_posts // controller
# Arguments for the query start here
&post_type=mytype 
&custom_fields=myfield
&include=title,custom_fields
&meta_key=myfield
&meta_value=myvalue
```

Have you tried the following?

- Debug the response: `http://www.example.org/api/get_page_index/?dev=1`
- Widget-style JSONP output: `http://www.example.org/api/get_recent_posts/?callback=show_posts_widget&read_more=More&count=3`
- Redirect on error: `http://www.example.org/api/posts/create_post/?callback_error=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.org%2Fhelp.html`

And could you post what you get out from the debug?

Comment: After adding the &dev=1 param to my query, the output is completely the same (formatted though, but no errors or anything). The other methods don't help much for my problem.
[Here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/22348/i-cant-set-meta-key-in-my-custom-post-type-query) I read that the meta_key and meta_value are not public query vars, so I'll probably have to map custom query vars manually as it is suggested in the first answer.

Comment: P.S. but I was hoping for an easier solution...

Comment: I'd suggest to intercept the `'posts_clauses'` filter and `var_dump()` the input `$pieces`. That gives you more insights about what happens in the query. Actually it will show you the query and you can there modify it.

Comment: Thanks! As you suggested [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/41069/exclude-specific-term-from-search), I did the var_dump and [this](http://pastebin.com/KHgGAYeK) is the output. No custom-field filters there. As I said, I was hoping for a possibility to filter directly via URL, as the meta_key and meta_value seem to be supported according to the JSON API docs.

Comment: Sorry, but I really don't know more than what I can read in the API docs. Your best bet with my help is to manually add meta query stuff in. Afaik there's an earlier hook where you should be able to `$query->set()` the meta keys in.