# add_query_vars and add_rewrite_rules

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I am looking for some clarity on what `add_rewrite_rules` does.

If I type in, or submit variables from a form, is it supposed to change the query variables to the pretty url?

Currently when I type in the pretty url, the page acts how I want. When I submit a form which redirects to a page with the query variables in the url, it also works fine. But I had thought that if I had typed in a url with the query variables, it would switch to the pretty url. It does not do that. Should it? Am I doing this wrong?

```
function add_query_vars($aVars) {
    $aVars[] .= 'var_state';
    $aVars[] .= 'var_clubs';
}
add_filter('query_vars', 'add_query_vars');

function add_rewrite_rules($aRules) {
    $aNewRules = array(
        'rv-clubs/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$' => 'index.php?pagename=rv-clubs&var_state=$matches[1]&var_clubs=$matches[2]'
    );
    $aRules = $aNewRules + $aRules;
    return $aRules;
}
add_filter('rewrite_rules_array', 'add_rewrite_rules');
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can see in [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/22349/1861) how `add_rewrite_rules` is being used, I don't think it applies to your case at all.

What you need to do is to redirect urls generated from the search from (I'm assuming something like `site.com/?s=term`) to a pretty URL. This article do it http://www.wptavern.com/how-to-make-the-wordpress-search-url-pretty